# ¿como hacer que aparezca un select apartir de la seleccion de varios selects a la ves?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

me refiero a que si yo selecciono un municipio me cargue una informacion de la bd que corresponda luego que si selecciono la eps me cargen los datos que correspondan al municipio y a la eps luego que si selecciono el regimen me cargen los datos que sean del municipio que sean de la eps seleccionada y que sean del regimen seleccionado

Comment: Puedes hacer llamados ajax cada vez que cambia el select

Comment: como lo haria? me podrias dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Sube al menos el modelo entidad relación y algun fragmento de como tienes la conexión a la bd para poderte ayudar

Comment: mira que tengo problemas con subir el codigo me presenta un error de maximos caracteres creo que la bd es muy grande, la conexion la tengo asi mira aqui podria enviartelo al correo u otro medio? te lo agradeceria?

Comment: class Constantes {
  const HOST = "localhost";
  const USER = "root";
  const PASSWORD = "";
  const DB = "teayudoeps";
 }
 
 class Configuracion extends Constantes{

  public $mysql = NULL; 

  public function conectarBD($bd = Constantes::DB)
  {
   date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
   $this->mysql = new mysqli(Constantes::HOST, Constantes::USER, Constantes::PASSWORD, $bd); 
   mysqli_set_charset($this->mysql, "utf8"); 
   return $this->mysql;

  }

Comment: la bd la tengo en mysql normal los selects los tengo asi

Comment: select id="id_departamento" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <option value=" 0">Seleccione</option>

Comment: y los lleno con consultas y los selects dependientes de uno solo los asi

Comment: con la funcion on change de jquery que amedida que cambie

Comment: envio la consulta a un archivo php con ajax y la muestro con el id.html(data)